# Not able to create patch file

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, perforce

I am using Eclipse as an IDE and perforce as a version control.

I want to create a Patch file of my code.

I followed all the steps but I am getting this error during my patch file creation.

[image: img1]

Comment: Have you taken the advice of the error message and checked the help provided?

Comment: Yes ,but It is not able to resolved my issue.

Comment: How is it 'not able to'? If you require people to read your mind to kow what you are asking then you will not get useful answers. The onus is on youi to ask a question that people can answer. If you want good answers you need to ask good questions.